# Django Forms - Format Select Field Time Value as AM/PM

Tags: python, django

I have a Django form select field with 15 min time slot options:

```
<select id="mytime" name="mytime">
<option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
<option value="2:15 PM">2:15 PM</option>
<option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option>
<option value="2:45 PM">2:45 PM</option>
...
```

The problem I have is that when I'm editing the instance values, the current time value will not be automatically selected unless I have the option values in 24h format such as `<option value="14:45:00">14:45:00</option>` as that is the matching database format.

**views.py**

```
times = []
for i in range(0, 24*4):
    times.append((datetime.combine(date.today(), time()) + timedelta(minutes=15) * i).time().strftime("%I:%M %p").lstrip('0'))
form = MyForm(instance=instance, 
       options=[( choice, choice ) for choice in times])
return ...
```

**forms.py**

```
self.fields['mytime'] = forms.ChoiceField(
                        required=True,
                        choices=options,
                        widget=forms.Select(
                            attrs={'class': 'myclass',}
                       ))
```

As this is a `Select` field, the widget will not accept the `format` attribute.

Any way around this?

How can I achieve AM/PM format in my drop down menu with the current value selected?

---

### Working code:

forms.py

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
options = kwargs.pop('options', None)
super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

self.fields['mytime'] = forms.ChoiceField(
                        required=True,
                        choices=options,
                        widget=forms.Select(
                            attrs={'class': 'myclass',}
                       ))
```

view.py

```
 form = MyForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance,
                   options=[( choice.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), choice.strftime("%I:%M %p").lstrip('0') ) for choice in times])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, everything would work if the markup looked like this

```
<option value="14:00:00">2:00 PM</option>
```

You could change **views.py** so that it generates the `choices` tuple with a value in 24h-format and a display string with a.m. and p.m.

```
times = []
for i in range(0, 24*4):
    times.append((datetime.combine(date.today(), time()) + timedelta(minutes=15) * i).time())
form = MyForm(instance=instance,
       options=[( choice.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), choice.strftime("%I:%M %p").lstrip('0') ) for choice in times])
return ...
```

Comment: So, after all, the error was triggered by a piece of code from the other solution and everything is working correctly! Thank you again for your time and your valuable feedback! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by passing the parameter [`initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#initial).

Something similar to the following should do the trick

```
if instance:
    mytime_initial = time.strptime(instance.mytime, '%I:%M %p').lstrip('0')
else:
    mytime_initial = None

self.fields['mytime'] = forms.ChoiceField(
    required=True,
    choices=options,
    initial=mytime_initial,
    widget=forms.Select(
        attrs={'class': 'myclass',}
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. You solution got me on the right track and once I converted the `mytime_initial` to a string, I got a working code. That being said, I'm still trying to use the @sthzg solution as it may require less code in my forms. Either way, thank you again for your time and feedback! Much appreciated!